# Keep getting an uncaught syntax error: unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, express

It's this part of my app.js file for my express mini app.

```
 var loginPost = function()

    user = {
        username: $('#username').val(),
        password: $('#password').val(),
    }; 

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/login',
        method: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: user
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data.username+"login successful");

        user = Cookies.get("loggedinId");

        wishForm()

     });
};
```

Says there is a uncaught syntax error on the line where it says user = { but i don't see anything wrong with it. any clues? thanks.

Comment: Starting Braces:  `var loginPost = function() {`

Answer (score 1):

You missed a `{`

```
var loginPost = function(){   // This { you missed

    user = {
        username: $('#username').val(),
        password: $('#password').val(),
    }; 

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/login',
        method: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: user
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data.username+"login successful");

        user = Cookies.get("loggedinId");

        wishForm()

     });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the braces and also remember to declare your variables so they dont pollute the global scope (unless thats what you're going for).

Answer (score 0):

You have missed

```
function(){ // This braces
```